# Vector Constructor Syntax Similar to Sigma

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation, vectors

Is there a syntax like $$\sum_{i=0}^n i^2$$ but for constructing vectors instead of summing?

Something like $$?_{i=0}^n i^2$$ would represent $$\begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 4 & 9 & ... & n^2\end{pmatrix}$$

If there isn't one, what would be the best (most compact) way of representing this behavior?

Comment: $\vec a=(a_0,a_1,...,a_n); a_i=i^2, 0\le i\le n$

Answer (score 1):

You could say $\vec a=(a_0,a_1,\dots,a_n),$ $a_i=i^2, 0\le i\le n.$

Comment: I was hoping for a more compact syntax. In this form, there is a lot of verbosity whose information is implicit in the sigma notation.